# Merging two lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6

When I try to merge two lines selecting them and using the Merge Tool in the Advanced Editing Menu I get an error which says that merging these lines would result in an incompatible geometry for this layer so that it is cancelled.

How can I merge lines?

Comment: What kind of datasoruce are the lines in?

Comment: They're on a line layer

Comment: I rather thought of shapefile/spatialite/postgis/GPX/CSV or else.

Comment: They're on Spatialite

Comment: If lines do not join at the ends merging would give a multilinestring instead of a linestring. Could that be your situation?

Comment: How do I know if they join? They are very close, but I don't know if they join

Comment: You can zoom in on the end points of both. Anyway, a table with MULTILINESTRING geometry would avoid the error message.

Comment: I am snapping the endpoints but it stills return an error. I don't understand the table thing. Sorry, I'm new to GIS and QGis!

Answer (score 3):

If you create a new spatialite layer with QGIS, you can select between Type:

`Point  MultiPoint  Line  Multiline  Polygon  Multipolygon`

The merging will only work errorfree if your layer is of type `Multi...`.

Even if you snap the end points of two lines, the direction of the two lines might be different, and QGIS does not create a single line, but tries to create a Multiline feature with 2 subelements.

What you can do, is to create a new multiline layer, copy all your line features into it, and work on with that.